# displaying a set of elements in a springboot application under the command line runner constructor

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm wondering if it is possible to display a set in a public command line runner method on a spring boot application in the same way I could display an array or list of elements using Arrays.asList.
Let's say this is my constructor in  the class

```
    @ElementCollection
    @Column(name="imagesURL")
    private List <String> items=new ArrayList<>();

    public Product(){}
    public Product(List<String>items);

       this.items=items;
-----------------------------------
       getters and setters
    }
```

then on my SpringBootAplication kind of

```
    Product product1=new Poduct(Arrays.asList("pixabay.com.jpg","pixabay.com.jpg","http//pixabay.com.jpg"));
```

would it be possible to do the same with a set? any similar method to Arrays.asList to display a set in this SpringBoot Application constructor ?...thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: Hi, can you share what you have tried? Is your goal is to display the entries in the set or to initialize one instance of Product with your a set of items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try something like this.

```
Product product1 = new Poduct(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("pixabay.com.jpg","pixabay.com.jpg","http//pixabay.com.jpg"));
```

or this

```
Product product1 = newPoduct(Arrays.asList("pixabay.com.jpg","pixabay.com.jpg","http//pixabay.com.jpg").stream().collect(Collectors.toSet()));
```

Answer (score 0):

We can create Set using Arrays.asList as an argument.

```
Set<Integer>  set = new HashSet<> (Arrays.asList(1 , 2 , 3));
```